# dle установка фб пикселя

Tags: facebook, dle

Столкнулся с проблемой, нужно установить фб пиксель на все страницы в header , но его в dle как такового нет и он отдельно устанавливается на каждую страницу, его обязательно проставлять на каждую страницу отдельно или есть какой то способ вставить один раз?

Answer (score 0):

Можно вставить в файл шаблона main.tpl между `<head> и </head>` тогда код будет на всех страницах сайта.